# how to retrieve data from helper class property using Linq query C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve list of data form `CPayment`, but when i write linq query, `CPaymentModel` class properties are loaded, but `TransactionHelper` class Properties are not loaded and can not be viewed

**How to access the Helper Class properties or how to get List of both Classes Helper and Non-Helper  properties ??** how to solve this problem..

**My Model Class Code is**

```
public class CPaymentModel<br>
{   
     public CPaymentModel()<br>
     {
        Transaction =new TransactionHelper();
     }

      //Local Class Properties     
      public UInt64 CardNo { get; set; }
      public DateTime FileDate { get; set; }        

      //Helper Class 
      public TransactionHelper Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionHelper<br>
{
      public int TransCode { get; set; }
      public DateTime TransDate { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller Code is:**

```
public ActionResult GetPersons([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
{
  var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();<br>
  var data2 = session.Query < CPayment > ().Select(row => new CPaymentModel()
  {
        CardNo = row.CardNo,<br>
        FileDate = row.FileDate,<br>
        Transaction =row.Transaction<br>
   }).ToList < CPaymentModel > ();<br>
  var list = data2.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
  return Json(list);
}
```

**Index Page (KendoUI-grid)Code  :**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid < CPaymentModel > ()
    .Name("PaymentInfo")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()<br>
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetPersons", "KendoDemo"))
 )
)
```

My Output Is:
[click] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKPU.png

Comment: From your example it is not clear where and how you store your data. Is this a database? Do you also store your TransactionHelper there? And what do you mean by being unable to access ar view it's properties? Do they contain null values? Or is it the whole row.Transaction which is null?

Comment: Is TransactionHelper declared within CPaymentModel? Or have you just not formatted your the code properly? Is there a list of CPaymentModel in your CPayment class, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();

var data2 = session.Query<CPayment>().Select(row => new CPaymentModel()
{
    CardNo = row.CardNo,
    Product = row.ProductDetails.Product,
    Subproduct = row.ProductDetails.Subproduct,
    FileDate = row.FileDate,
    Transaction =new TransactionHelper()
    {
        TransCode = row.Transaction.TransCode;
        TransDate = row.Transaction.TransDate
    }
}).ToList<CPaymentModel>();
var list = data2.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
```

Comment: Only Change to Index Code (Kendo UI):<br>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CPaymentModel>()<br>
    .Name("PaymentInfo")<br>
    .Columns(col =><br>
        {<br>
            col.Bound(c => c.CardNo);<br>
            col.Bound(c => c.FileDate);<br>
            col.Bound(c => c.Transaction.TransCode);<br>
            col.Bound(c => c.Transaction.TransDate);<br>
        }<br>
      )<br>
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource<br>
        .Ajax()<br>
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetPersons", "DataBinder"))<br>
    )<br>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new object of transaction helper use this method. Here I have created a new object and used the initializer syntax to set the properties.

```
var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();

var data2 = session.Query<CPayment>().Select(row => new CPaymentModel()
{
    CardNo = row.CardNo,
    Product = row.ProductDetails.Product,
    Subproduct = row.ProductDetails.Subproduct,
    FileDate = row.FileDate,
    Transaction = new TransactionHelper
    {
        TransCode = row.Transaction.TransCode,
        TransDate = row.Transaction.TransDate
    }
}).ToList<CPaymentModel>();
var list = data2.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
```

**Did you know?** you can always write a *lambda function* instead of a *lambda expression* like:

```
row =>
{
    CPaymentModel cpModel = new CPaymentModel()
    {
        CardNo = row.CardNo,
        Product = row.ProductDetails.Product,
        Subproduct = row.ProductDetails.Subproduct,
        FileDate = row.FileDate,
        Transaction = new TransactionHelper()
    };
    cpModel.Transaction = new Transaction();
    cpModel.Transaction.TransCode = row.Transaction.TransCode;
    cpModel.Transaction.TransDate = row.Transaction.TransDate;

    return cpModel;
}
```

This is a perfectly valid construct. It will be useful when you cant do everything with initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe call Include method with path to Transaction property as an argument, indicating that EF should load it with all properties

```
var session = SessionManager.GetCurrentSession();

 var data2 = session.Query<CPayment>().**Include("CPayment.Transaction").**Select(row => new CPaymentModel()
 {
        CardNo = row.CardNo,
        Product = row.ProductDetails.Product,
        Subproduct = row.ProductDetails.Subproduct,
        FileDate = row.FileDate,
        Transaction =row.Transaction
   }).ToList<CPaymentModel>();
var list = data2.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
```